# Function that is holomorphic on unit disc, bounded, and converges uniformly to 0 given some conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

In the proof above what exactly is $\Omega'$ defined as? Is it precisely the part that is NOT within (or on the boundary of) the unit disc?

If so, I'm not sure how this proof makes sense -- if $g(z)$ is holomorphic on all of $\Omega'$ and has a cluster of zeros, how are we guaranteed that the boundary of the disc in this sector also is identically 0? Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega'$ is any set which extends from $\Bbb D$ in the region of angles given. Then, by showing $g(z)$ is holomorphic on all of $\Omega'$, it follows that $g\equiv0$. As an extension of $f$, $f$ must also be identically $0$.